Proving equivalence of alternative formulation of the Axiom of Choice
I'm trying to establish the equivalence of the follow two assertions (Exercise 1.6 in page 52 of Set Theory and the Continuum Problem by Smullyan and Fitting).
AC. If $A$ is a non-empty set of non-empty sets, there is a function $f$ with domain $A$ such that for any $x \in A$, $f(x) \in A$.
Th. For every non-empty set $A$ there is a function $f$ such that for every proper subset $x$ of $A$, $f(x) \in x$.
I had no problem proving AC $\Rightarrow$ Th. For the reverse implication, however, I'm stuck. Here's my reasoning.
Claim: Th implies AC.
Incomplete proof. Let $A$ be a non-empty set of non-empty sets and consider the union set $\bigcup A$. Since $A$ is non-empty, so is $\bigcup A$, thus by Th there is a function $f$ such that for all proper subset $x$ of $\bigcup A$, $f(x) \in x$.
Let $y \in A$. Then $y \subseteq \bigcup A$, so if $y$ is a proper subset then $f(y) \in y$ as required. It remains to show that $y$ is a proper subset of $\bigcup A$. $\square$
I can't figure how to show that $y$ is a proper subset of $\bigcup A$. I've tried assuming $\bigcup A \subseteq y$, hoping to reach a contradiction, but the furthest I got in this direction is concluding that in this case, for any $x \in A$, $x \subseteq y$. Any help is appreciated.

The statement of Th is incorrect. It is inconsistent as stated, so you cannot prove AC $\implies$ Th. Rather than "for every proper subset", it should say "for every non-empty subset". After all, $\varnothing$ is a proper subset of $A$, and it is impossible to have $f(\varnothing) \in \varnothing$.

@AlexKruckman you're right obviously. I even unconsciously acknowledged it in my proof of AC $\Longrightarrow$ Th, because there I applied AC to the set $P = \mathcal P(A) \setminus \emptyset$.
But checking the book, the statement of Th really says for every proper subset instead of non-empty subset. It seems changing the statement of Th to non-empty makes the proof work both ways, so that must have been the intended statement.

NB I submitted an edit to this question which is obviously wrong (as I realized seconds afterwards) but apparently I have no way to retract it :( Sorry.

Do the authors define "proper" anywhere? It's rare but not unheard of for people to use the convention that $\emptyset$ is not a proper subset of any set. I assume that is what's going on here. See eg this

@IzaakvanDongen the authors seem to adopt the usual notion of proper subset; first they define proper informally on p. 7 by saying "(...) proper subset of $B$--that is, with a subset of $B$ which is not all of $B$ (it leaves out at least one element of $B$)."  then on p. 37: "we shall use the notation $x \subset y$ to mean that $x$ is a proper subset of $y$ ($x \subseteq y$ but not $y \subseteq x$).

Another amazing equivalence is the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the Tychonoff's theorem

Fair enough @purpleflyer! That is weird. Another way to fix it so Th does become equivalent to AC is to replace "$f(x) \in x$" by "$f(x) \in A \setminus x$".
